# boundary detection after Canny Edge

Tags: java, edge-detection

I've tried an open source java implementation of Canny Edge. I only need the boundary (the outline) of the image but there are extra lines in the output. Is there any way I could remove those lines after using Canny Edge (is there another algorithm)? Or are there other ways I could modify the program such that it will only detect the outline?

I've tried [this one](http://www.tomgibara.com/computer-vision/canny-edge-detector).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the outline you are looking for is a single "long" connected line,  you could filter out "short" lines.

One way to do it would be by computing the area of those lines with a [connected-component labeling algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling) and keeping only the line with the largest area (i.e. largest number of pixels).

Comment: yes, it's actually a shape.. can i use this after canny edge?

Comment: Yes, you should compute the areas of the lines after the canny edge detection process.