# Success or failure of the Canny edge detector

Tags: scikit-image, edge-detection, canny-operator

Using the canny edge detection and gaussian blur it  [detects an edge following this tutorial](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_canny.html). However the question here is how to find out if it was actually able to find out an edge or not automatically? Is there a relation with the  [longest boundary detection after Canny Edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190636/boundary-detection-after-canny-edge)? Or is it as simple as looking for the entire matrix filled with 0s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this tutorial, the parameters are tuned to get rid of spurious edges.

If you only want to known which pixels are edges, it is "as simple as looking for the entire matrix filled with 0s". If you need them in order, use a tracing algorithm such as here: http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/downloads_V3/root_downloads/tutorials/contour_tracing_Abeer_George_Ghuneim/alg.html